# How to free memory on stack mid-function call

Tags: c, memory-management

Say I have an array arr[10], and then I copy all elements to another array, arr2[20]. I no longer need arr, so I do arr=arr2 to move its pointer to the new array. Is the memory that was used by arr[10] still used, or is it freed automatically? If it's still used, is there a way for me to free it before reassigning the pointer?

Comment: You will need to post code since what you describe is not possible (i.e. have arr[10] and then later arr=arr2).

Comment: thanks Jim, I now realize that. Do you know how I can reassign an array variable to another array?

Comment: By using a *pointer*. You can assign the pointer to `arr` and then later point it to `arr2` based on what you are trying to do.

Comment: But, in any case, as the other answers say, you cannot deallocate stack memory before the function ends unless you scope the use of the array, but even *then* there's no guarantees since the compiler can do whatever the heck it wants.

Comment: great! thanks a lot; this really helps. I was a bit confused about arrays not being pointers.

Comment: They "act like" or "decay to" a pointer when being passed to a function, so there is a bit of a grey area with how arrays are seen in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declared arr like `int arr[10];` then it will be stored on the [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation), and will be freed when the function ends. You generally **can't** free stack memory mid function.

If you defined it using `malloc()` then it will be on the heap and you have to use `free()` to free it. Or else it will be a memory leak and be freed after your program exits. However, even if you get a memory leak, you computer will always be able to retrieve that memory because of [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).

Answer (score 0):

> Is the memory that was used by arr[10] still used, or is it freed automatically?

It depends on how you actually declare your array.

- If you declare it as an automatic variable, then it's freed automatically when the function call ends.
- If you do some dynamic allocation, then it will exist after the function call ends, and you would have to free it manually.